# Why are buffered versions of inputs used in Verilog simulation models?

Tags: verilog, simulation

Like this:

```
model EFUSE_MODEL (
  input PG_MODE,
  ...
);
  ...
  buf (pg_mode_buf, PG_MODE);
// the body of this model uses pg_mode_buf only
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Verilog simulation standpoint, the `buf` instance makes almost no difference in the code that you posted.  Since there is no optional delay specified, there will be no delay from `PG_MODE` to `pg_mode_buf`.  One minor difference is if `PG_MODE` is `z`, `pg_mode_buf` will become `x`.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, *Table 28-4—Truth tables for multiple output logic gates*.

It is common to create Verilog models of analog circuits to be used in digital simulations.  Perhaps this model was created from a schematic diagram where there was some kind of buffer on this input signal, and the person who created the model wanted it to closely mirror the schematic topology.  The Std states:

> Gates provide a much closer one-to-one mapping between the actual
> circuit and the model.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons behind this.

1. A lot of designs require manual placement of I/O buffer gates, even if the the rest of the model is written at RTL. Some people get into the habit of writing this way even when not required.
2. Some tool require connections to gate level primitives at the top-level boundaries. For example SDF back annotation of timing information, or cross domain simulation like mixed analog-digital
3. Automatically generated code from another medium or language. Other domains separate the naming of a port with the single that connects to that port. Inserting a buffer is one way of renaming the signal. There are other was of accomplishing that without inserting a buffer.

You really should be asking the people who provided the model.